# Where does django get initial fixtures from on manage.py test?

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I am trying to run `./manage.py test` **without** fixtures. I've deleted all fixtures I found from the project and made `./manage.py flush`. When I `./manage.py syncdb` I can see that `Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)`.

But when I run single test file `./manage.py test hello.tests.tests_selenium_login` which involves no fixtures directly it somehow finds fixtures and prints that `Installed 84 object(s) from 2 fixture(s)`

Where are these fixture supposed to be?

**upd**

Solved by recloning repo. But that is an overkill, I suppose. And does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django looks for `fixtures` in the fixtures folder of each application by default, as well as where you specify in the [FIXTURE_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-FIXTURE_DIRS) setting.

What is happening in your case is that there is no [`initial_data` fixture](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/initial-data/#automatically-loading-initial-data-fixtures), which is the one that gets loaded when you run syncdb/migrate. The fixture to load must be specified in the [fixtures attribute of the testcase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/tools/#topics-testing-fixtures) you run in the second command.